# Large form in single screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am making a an form which is almost 20 page long in objective c for ipad,and it should be in single screen ,and it will cross the 20,0000 scroll unit .Can someone tell me what is correct way to approach to this problem

Comment: Use tableview with multiple kinds of cell I suppose? it doesnt matter how many pages, the matter is the kind of data and the design for each field

Comment: better to divide them in pages and display with navigation controller.

Comment: you can devide it in views with segment controll

Comment: You can better divide the form in parts and also put something to show user his progress done in form that will make the UI better for user.

Comment: My problem is that i was using freeform and had increased the hight to 10,000 but now auto layout is not supporting above 10,000 for scroll view . The form should be continuous and i dont want to re write everything. So is there any i can use this views in a table view ..but all the views are of different size

Answer (score 1):

There are two approach to your problem
You need UItoolbar for better experience

1. Tableview with multiple cell, detect which cell is selected and show picker and toolbar state (whether precious/next button is selected)accordingly (Preferable)
2. ScrollView with stackviews, scroll manually depending upon frame of the stackview

Comment: My problem is that i was using freeform and had increased the hight to 10,000 but now auto layout is not supporting above 10,000 for scroll view . The form should be continuous and i dont want to re write everything. So is there any i can use this views in a table view ..but all the views are of different sizes

Comment: Better try to group the form items and keep one group in a page and use Next and Previous buttons to navigate to back and forward. In a page use UITableView to keep the form items, use different UITableViewCells that will simplify the headache of maintaining the auto layouts. Even you can keep in multiple sections if needed. So that each subgroup of a group can be categorised with section header titles.